# jQuery Serializing Brackets [ ] From Form Name Post to PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I'm serializing form data, the input names have brackets in them i.e. 
    
when I serialize it with jquery to POST it to my php file for processing, it looks like this - test%5Btesting%5D=some input.  My php file on the backend is not seeing these names when I try to grab it with:
    echo $_POST['test[testing]'];

if I try just getting the info using the name test it shows it as an array.  How do I tell php that the brackets are part of the field name?

```
<input name="test[testing]">
echo $_POST['test[testing]'];
```

My php file on the backend is not seeing these names when I try to grab it

Comment: How are you serlializing your form and how are you posting it to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP special cases square brackets in POST and GET data.

Access it with:

```
$_POST['test']['testing']
```

This allows you to construct a form with data that PHP will deserialize into a nested array / associative array structure that your server-side code can iterate over.

Some other form handling libraries have adopted this format, e.g. [Express.js's body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions) library has an optional *extended* mode which supports this.

PHP has no native support for constructing a flat data structure (where `$_POST['test[testing]']` would work), but you could read the raw data with:

```
$post_body_string = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

… and then write your own URL encoded form data parser.

Comment: Thank you!  It looks very much like JavaScript!  Can't believe I didnt realize this.

Comment: what if the ID had another set of brackets inside like this form_fields[7029d77][].  I tried $_POST['form_fields][7029d77][] and got a syntax error.

Comment: `7029d77` isn't a decimal number, it needs quotes around it in PHP

Comment: sorry I typed it too fast, i meant the empty brackets after everything i.e. form_fields['7029d77'] [ -- empty -- ].  I was reading somewhere it may be an array within an array and I have to iterate over it to get the POST value?